# Query to find and subtract two timestamps associated with the same identifier

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm very new to BigQuery and not terribly familiar with SQL. I have a table of data that looks like this, where `MyDate` is a `Timestamp` object:

| Row | MyDate | StateTransition | MyIdentifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-23 00:08:00 UTC | Start | 6371 |
| 2 | 2022-10-10 01:17:14 UTC | Finished | 6371 |
| 3 | 2022-09-26 04:51:40 UTC | Start | 7768 |
| 4 | 2022-10-05 03:44:32 UTC | Finished | 7768 |

etc.

My query looks something like

```
SELECT *
FROM <my-data-source>
WHERE (StateTransition="Start" OR StateTransition="Finished")
ORDER BY MyIdentifier, MyDate
```

What I'm trying to do is calculate the elapsed time (in days) between the `Start` and `Finished` timestamps associated with each `MyIdentifier`, and to have that displayed in another column. It could look like:

| Row | MyDate | StateTransition | MyIdentifier | ElapsedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-23 00:08:00 UTC | Start | 6371 |  |
| 2 | 2022-10-10 01:17:14 UTC | Finished | 6371 | 0.33 |
| 3 | 2022-09-26 04:51:40 UTC | Start | 7768 |  |
| 4 | 2022-10-05 03:44:32 UTC | Finished | 7768 | 0.04 |

Alternatively, it could even be flattened a little to something like:

| Row | StartTransition | FinishedTransition | MyIdentifier | ElapsedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-23 00:08:00 UTC | 2022-10-10 01:17:14 UTC | 6371 | 0.33 |
| 2 | 2022-09-26 04:51:40 UTC | 2022-10-05 03:44:32 UTC | 7768 | 0.04 |

I've tried looking through the BigQuery docs and Stack Overflow but haven't found anything that addresses this use case of selecting items from multiple rows with a common identifier and then performing an operation on them. It seems like subtracting the two timestamps would be done with the [TIMESTAMP_DIFF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_diff) function.

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-09-23 00:08:00 UTC' MyDate, 'Start' StateTransition, 6371 MyIdentifier, 'aaa' AS author UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-10-10 01:17:14 UTC' MyDate, 'Finished' StateTransition, 6371 MyIdentifier, 'bbb' AS author UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-09-26 04:51:40 UTC' MyDate, 'Start' StateTransition, 7768 MyIdentifier, 'ccc' AS author  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-10-05 03:44:32 UTC' MyDate, 'Finished' StateTransition, 7768 MyIdentifier, 'ccc' AS author
)
SELECT MyIdentifier,
       ARRAY_AGG(author ORDER BY MyDate LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS author,
       MIN(MyDate) AS StartTransition,
       MAX(MyDate) AS FinishedTransition,
       TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(MyDate), MIN(MyDate), DAY) AS ElapsedTime,
  FROM sample_table
 WHERE (StateTransition="Start" OR StateTransition="Finished")
 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]

If *Start* and *Finished* has different *author* name and you want the name of *Finished*, you can use below instead.

> ARRAY_AGG(author ORDER BY MyDate **DESC** LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS author,

Answer (score 1):

For flattened result, you might consider below using an aggregation.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-09-23 00:08:00 UTC' MyDate, 'Start' StateTransition, 6371 MyIdentifier UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-10-10 01:17:14 UTC' MyDate, 'Finished' StateTransition, 6371 MyIdentifier UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-09-26 04:51:40 UTC' MyDate, 'Start' StateTransition, 7768 MyIdentifier UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-10-05 03:44:32 UTC' MyDate, 'Finished' StateTransition, 7768 MyIdentifier
)
SELECT MyIdentifier, 
       MIN(MyDate) AS StartTransition,
       MAX(MyDate) AS FinishedTransition,
       TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MAX(MyDate), MIN(MyDate), DAY) AS ElapsedTime,
  FROM sample_table
 WHERE (StateTransition="Start" OR StateTransition="Finished")
 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]

But for the intermediate result, we need a window function.

```sql
SELECT *,
       IF(
         StateTransition = 'Finished',
         TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MyDate, FIRST_VALUE(IF(StateTransition = 'Start', MyDate, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w, DAY),
         NULL
       ) AS ElapsedTime
  FROM sample_table
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY MyIdentifier ORDER BY MyDate);
```

[image]

and if you want flattend result from the above result (using a window function), the query will looks like below which shows same result as the first query using an aggregation.

```sql
SELECT MyIdentifier,
       FIRST_VALUE(IF(StateTransition = 'Start', MyDate, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w AS StartTransition,
       MyDate AS FinishedTransition,
       IF(
         StateTransition = 'Finished',
         TIMESTAMP_DIFF(MyDate, FIRST_VALUE(IF(StateTransition = 'Start', MyDate, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER w, DAY),
         NULL
       ) AS ElapsedTime
  FROM sample_table
QUALIFY StateTransition = 'Finished'
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY MyIdentifier ORDER BY MyDate);
```

Comment: Thank you! The first part of your answer using an aggregation worked perfectly. If there are additional columns I'd like to output, would you be able to tell me how to do that? There's an `author` field I'd like to see but when I put that in the `SELECT` I get a `GROUP BY`-related error as `author` isn't part of the aggregation.

Comment: @EvanR, same `MyIdenifier` has same `author` name ? If so, just putting `author` in 2nd column in `SELECT` and using `GROUP BY 1, 2`  would be enough.

Comment: This may be beyond the scope of this question, but I'm seeing that MyIdentifier *doesn't* always have the same author name and is thus affecting the query results if I include it (`ElapsedTime` is coming back as `0`). Do you know of a way that I could display the author name without affecting the elapsed time? I'd be fine with just overwriting the author name in the `Finish` transition using the `Start` transition author value if that made things easier.

Comment: @EvanR, not sure I clearly understood your explanation but kindly check out the another anwser if it properly handles your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select *, timestamp_diff(Transition_Finished, Transition_Start, day) as ElapsedTime
from your_table
pivot (max(MyDate) Transition for StateTransition in ('Start', 'Finished'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Use below to test

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-09-23 00:08:00 UTC' MyDate, 'Start' StateTransition, 6371 MyIdentifier UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-10-10 01:17:14 UTC' MyDate, 'Finished' StateTransition, 6371 MyIdentifier UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-09-26 04:51:40 UTC' MyDate, 'Start' StateTransition, 7768 MyIdentifier UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-10-05 03:44:32 UTC' MyDate, 'Finished' StateTransition, 7768 MyIdentifier
)
select *, timestamp_diff(Transition_Finished, Transition_Start, day) as ElapsedTime
from your_table
pivot (max(MyDate) Transition for StateTransition in ('Start', 'Finished'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Are you certain you're looking at the correct sample data in my question? It's the table at the very top. Your answer doesn't seem to take into account `MyIdentifier` and how to group or aggregate rows with it. I also get an `Unrecognized name: Transition_Finished` error.

Comment: yes, I am sure I use correct sample data. see test example in my update. the way how it groups and aggregates is the trick behind using `pivot` :o)

Comment: Ah, you're right! Had to just run the `pivot` command on its own to see how it creates new column names.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for each `MyIdentifier` you should have only one start and one finish, so you can simply split and join:

```
;WITH 
ts AS ( SELECT * FROM <my-data-source> WHERE StateTransition = 'Start'),
tf AS ( SELECT * FROM <my-data-source> WHERE StateTransition = 'Finished')
SELECT 
    ts.MyIdentifier, 
    ts.MyDate StartTransition, 
    tf.MyDate FinishedTransition, 
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts.MyDate, tf.MyDate, DAY) ElapsedTime
FROM ts
LEFT JOIN tf on ts.MyIdentifier = tf.MyIdentifier
```

**UPDATE**

If you have more start and finish for each identifier you need to choice which one to keep, I will assume you want to keep the 1st start and the last finish:

```
;WITH 
ts AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MyIdentifier ORDER BY MyDate) n
    FROM <my-data-source> WHERE StateTransition = 'Start'),
tf AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by MyIdentifier ORDER BY MyDate DESC) n
    FROM <my-data-source> WHERE StateTransition = 'Finished')
SELECT 
    ts.MyIdentifier, 
    ts.MyDate StartTransition, 
    tf.MyDate FinishedTransition, 
    TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ts.MyDate, tf.MyDate, DAY) ElapsedTime       
FROM ts
LEFT JOIN tf on ts.MyIdentifier = tf.MyIdentifier and tf.n=1
WHERE ts.n=1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm seeing two rows associated with the same identifier, though. The first row is correct but the second row isn't and appears to show a `FinishedTransition` date not associated with that identifier. You are correct in that there's only one start and one finish for each identifier.

Comment: If you get more rows for each identifier, it means there are more start/finish for each identifier.